# How to find matching colors in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, match

I have this list of colors:

```
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white'];
```

This is my array objects:

```
products = [
  {id: 1, ​name: "Apple", color: ['Brown','black'] },
  {id: 2, name: "Orange", color: ['red']},
  ​{id: 3, name: "Grape", color: ['red','white']},
 ​ {id: 4, name: "Banana", color: ['yellow']},
  {id: 5, name: "Mandarin", color: ['blue']}
];
```

I want to return an array of the matching colors like so: `[Orange,Grape,Banana];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it traverses through product lists and checks if the color list contains one of the colors

```
const list = products.filter((obj)=>{
        return obj.color.some(c=>colors.includes(c))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a filter and a map...

```js
const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white'];

const products = [
  {id: 1, name: "Apple", color: ['Brown','black'] },
  {id: 2, name: "Orange", color: ['red']},
  {id: 3, name: "Grape", color: ['red','white']},
  {id: 4, name: "Banana", color: ['yellow']},
  {id: 5, name: "Mandarin", color: ['blue']}
];

const arr = products.filter(product => {
  return product.color.some(color => colors.some(c => c === color))
}).map(product => product.name);

console.log(arr);
```

This should be what you're looking for as it produces the correct list of items as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This runs 2 filters to find matching colors

```
products.filter(e => e.color.filter( c=> colors.includes(c)).length>0)
```

```js
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white']

products = [
  {id: 1, name: "Apple", color: ['Brown','black'] },
  {id: 2, name: "Orange", color: ['red']},
  {id: 3, name: "Grape", color: ['red','white']},
  {id: 4, name: "Banana", color: ['yellow']},
  {id: 5, name: "Mandarin", color: ['blue']}
]

let filtered = products.filter(e => e.color.filter( c=> colors.includes(c)).length>0)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let requiredArray = products.filter(({ color }) => colors.some(item => color.includes(item)));

console.log(requiredArray);
```